# Splitting Google sentiment analysis response into separate columns and generating `None` for cells with no value

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis, google-natural-language

**Goal**

I want to split the response from Google Sentiment Analysis into four columns, then merge with original content dataframe.

**Situation**

I'm running the Google sentiment analysis on a column of text in a python dataframe.
Here's a sample for one of the returned rows. The column is 'sentiment':

`magnitude: 0.6000000238418579\nscore: -0.6000000238418579`

I then need to split that cell into four new columns, one for magnitude, one for it's returned value, one for score, and one for it's returned value.

**What I've tried**

Currently, I'm using this method to do that:

`df02 = df01['sentiment'].astype(str).str.split(expand=True)`

I'm then merging those four columns with the original dataframe that contains the analyzed `text` field and other values.

However, if sentiment returns no results, the `sentiment` cell is empty. And if all rows have empty `sentiment` cells, then it won't create four new columns. And that breaks my attempt to merge the two dataframes.

So I'm trying to understand how I can insert `None` into the new four column cells if the `sentiment` cell value is empty in the source dataframe. That way, at least I'll have four columns, with the values for each of the four new cells being `None`.

I've received input that I should use `apply()` and `fillna`, but I'm not understanding how that should be handled in my instance, and the documentation isn't clear to me. It seems like the method above needs code added that inserts `None` if no value is detected, but I'm not familiar enough with Python or pandas to know where to start on that.

**EXAMPLE**

What the data returned looks like. If all rows have no entry, then it won't create the four columns, which is required for my next method of merging this dataframe back into the dataframe with the original text content.

```
|index|0|1|2|3|
|---|---|---|---|---|
|0|||||
|1|||||
|2|||||
|3|||||
|4|||||
|5|magnitude:|0\.6000000238418579|score:|-0\.6000000238418579|
|6|magnitude:|0\.10000000149011612|score:|0\.10000000149011612|
|7|magnitude:|0\.10000000149011612|score:|-0\.10000000149011612|
|8|magnitude:|0\.699999988079071|score:|-0\.699999988079071|
|9|magnitude:|0\.699999988079071|score:|-0\.30000001192092896|
|10|magnitude:|0\.699999988079071|score:|-0\.30000001192092896|
```

Comment: post a data with one row giving empty

Comment: Thx @onyambu. I think you're requesting an example of the rows with empty cells? I added that to my post.

Comment: What column are you using for merging? Or are you using the index?

Comment: @onyambu I'm using this: `df03 = pd.merge(df01, df02, left_index=True, right_index=True)` So taking the original dataframe and merging it with the new sentiment dataframe to create a new 3rd dataframe.

Comment: Hi @dsx, can you provide sample data and documentation you are following to achieve your requirement?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar I got this sorted out. This is what worked: `pd.DataFrame(df['sentiment'].apply(sentiment_pass).tolist(),columns=['magnitude', 'score'], index=df.index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @dsx, the responses from [Google Sentiment Analysis](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/sentiment-tutorial) can be split into four columns by using the below code :

```
pd.DataFrame(df['sentiment'].apply(sentiment_pass).tolist(),columns=['magnitude', 'score'], index=df.index)
```

Sentiment Analysis is used to identify the prevailing emotions within the text using natural language processing. For more information, you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-sentiment).